# Can brace expansion be performed within the `at` command?

Tags: shell, at

In `bash`, brace expansion is performed as a shell operation before executing the command.[1](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Operation.html#Shell-Operation) This means the following will work:
`echo {1..10} >output | at -m now`

The output will be `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`.

What does not work is an attempt to perform brace expansion within the `at` command which warns that commands will be executed by `/bin/sh`, which in my case is linked to `dash` which does not seem to support range expansion using braces.

```
$ at - now
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> echo {1..10} >output
at> <EOT>
```

This will run the command in `dash` (or Bourne or whatever shell you have `/bin/sh` linked to) resulting in the output `{1..10}`.

How can brace expansion be performed when using the `at` command this way?

---

I am interested in seeing other solutions to this besides the one I've posted as an answer, such as being able to execute commands with `bash` from within the `at` prompt. It seems like more effort than necessary to create a script for every single line command that is run from the `at` prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three straightforward other options. One is a bit fragile and relies on implementation details of the shells, another uses [here documents](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04) to provide the script to `bash` inline, and the other just uses `-c` to pass a single line in.

---

Most reliably and portably, use a [here document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04):

```
$ at now
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> bash <<'EOF'
at> echo {1..5} >/tmp/output
at> EOF
at> <EOT>
job 24 at Mon Mar 23 20:41:20 2015
$ cat /tmp/output
1 2 3 4 5
```

`<<word` declares a here document that is provided as standard input to `bash` and lasts until `word`. By quoting `'EOF'` the document is not subject to expansion by the shell, so you can write a `$` in the body without `dash` eating it. Your script can include anything other than `EOF` (or your word of choice) at the start of a line.

This is really the approach I'd recommend — you can very nearly write it exactly as though you'd been using `bash` all along, with just an extra line at the start and end to show there's anything going on.

---

If it's really just a single line, just [use `bash -c`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoking-Bash-1) to pass a single command to run:

```
$ at now
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> bash -c 'echo {1..3} >/tmp/output'
at> <EOT>
job 25 at Mon Mar 23 20:50:03 2015
$ cat /tmp/output
1 2 3
```

That can be a bit of a hassle when you have quotes to use inside the command as well.

---

Most hackishly: `atd` generally sends jobs to the shell as standard input (but I don't believe it's required to). Shells generally read standard input line-by-line (but they are not required to behave in that way).

If your implementations do behave that way then you can perform a nasty trick to run your job under another shell:

```
$ at now
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> bash
at> echo {1..10} >/tmp/output
at> <EOT>
job 22 at Mon Mar 23 20:40:00 2015
$ cat /tmp/output
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

This works because `sh` reads the first line and executes `bash`, and `bash` then gets to read the rest of standard input as its commands. This is pretty fragile, but is the least intrusive version when it works.

`dash` itself is notably fiddlier in this area than many shells, and filling up an internal buffer is more important to it. Other simplistic shells, such as BusyBox's `sh`, tend to have the line-buffering behaviour.

---

Finally, although you're never *required* to use a separate script file, in many cases it actually will be the better option rather than trying to be too clever about things. When your jobs are single-use or programmatically-generated, these are reasonable options, but any other time sucking it up and using a standalone script is probably worth it in maintenance terms.

I really can't recommend the stdin exploitation of the last option at all, but it's a cute trick.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. That "here document" method is exactly the type of solution I was seeking. I knew there was something like `bash -c`, but I was really looking for the freedom to redirect not just to `bash`, but any unforeseen scenario in the future that is similar. Portability being a big bonus.

Comment: And, if you're lazy, you can use the "here document", but end it with <EOT>, skipping over the `EOF`. It will give you an error message, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found so far is to write a script (let's call it expandme.sh) which specifies the use of `bash` as the interpreter.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo {1..10} >output
```

Then, run the script from the `at` prompt:

```
$ at - now
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> expandme.sh
at> <EOT>
```

Now the script will get us out of the `dash`/`Bourne` exile that at put us in and perform the expansion before dumping the output.